# Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0/Suggested fixes haven't worked

Tags: mysql, heroku, sequelize.js

I've been digging through this issue and have not been able to figure out the solution from any of the posts. I'm hoping someone can please help me get this figured out so I can get my app deployed to Heroku.

I've tried setting the environment variables and including the dialect in both models `index.js` and `config.json`. I'm declaring it in config.

`config.json`:

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "ragnar_db",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "ragnar_db",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "production": {
    "use_env_variable": "JAWSDB_URL",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  }
}
```

`modles/index.js`:

```
"use strict";

var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
var basename = path.basename(module.filename);
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
var config = require(__dirname + "/../config/config.json")[env];
var db = {};

if (config.use_env_variable) {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
  console.log(process.env);
} else {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database,
    config.username,
    config.password,
    config
  );
}

fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function (file) {
    return (
      file.indexOf(".") !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === ".js"
    );
  })
  .forEach(function (file) {
    var model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function (modelName) {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Comment: 1) In which line does the error occur? 2) I think you should be calling sequelize.authenticate() before setting up the models and associations..

Comment: Error occured in the Sequelize constructor. Instead of declaring config after the necessary object declarations you need to also include an object with host and dialect declared. You can see the example below, and see the other solution which sets env properly without needing a .env file. .authenticate wouldn't be necessary for something this simple, but used when you're connecting to info that a specific user view. For example a user page or api call, you would want to run .authenticate to check the authentication values with a sign-in/sign-up redirect.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to provide the code for older Sequelize version this way.

```
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
  console.log(process.env);
} else {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database,
    config.username,
    config.password,
    {
      host: "host_name",
      dialect: "Your_dialect"
  });
}
```

The other answer is to reinitialize your Sequelize-cli and run the commands for provisioning your db. Then run Sequelize -init, if you set up everything through the terminal the init will have your JAWSDB_URL stored for environmental variables and set it in your node and heroku environment. Otherwise it will ask you to paste your JAWSDB_URL into the terminal inquirer. This is a change from older versions to allow Sequelize to hide db info better than before, but if you're using the newest version with old code must be in both your conf.json/config.js and in models/index.js.